# VS Code Joining collaboration session failure

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error when a coworker shares a VS Code liveshare link:

```
Joining collaboration session: User does not have permission to connect to the workspace, please ask host to provide access to the session.
```

Anyone know what that is referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: The error seems to be related to the timeout of the permission for your connection.
Your co-worker needs to approve the connection when you are trying to connect to that link. Please verify if your co-worker has allowed your connection.